# wrong timeStamp for rAF in PhantomJS browser

Tags: phantomjs, requestanimationframe

I used phantomJS browser for my test scripts and used requestAnimationFrame(rAF) for animation process. When I start the test script in phantomJS, the timeStamp gets wrong values in rAF. But it works fine in other browsers.

Refer the various timeStamp value as below

phantomJS: 1486032943535.4844

chrome: 3918.8199997879565

firefox: 2997.8451083288005

How to fix this issue in phanthomjs?

Comment: Have you tried the latest PhantomJS 2.5beta?

Comment: @Vaviloff: The same issue throws in 2.5beta version

Comment: Maybe you could file a bug report?